# How to make GCC report every occurence of an undeclared symbol?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

When i rename a symbol I usually fail to rename all occurences in my code manually.

When GCC reports error about this, it only tells "(each undeclared symbol reported only once)".

I want it to report all occurences. Is it possible?

Comment: You can use `grep -n` with your symbol on your source file, having line numbers. I don't know about gcc but you can search near gcc compiling options (such as -Wall for example)

Comment: if you are using vim, u can change all the occurances of a word by using the substitute command. :%s/original/replacement/cg
the last 2 options are for confirmation and multiple occurance in the same line..

Comment: One could also use an IDE that supports refactoring (Eclipse for example). This might be more save then a simple search&replace.

Answer (score 3):

My first question is: why?  When I change the name of a symbol, I do it
using global search and replace: in my editor (vim):

```
:argdo %s/\<oldname\>/newname/g
```

(This changes all instances of `oldname` into `newname`, in all files in
the editors list of arguments, but only if `oldname` is a complete
symbol; i.e. `someoldname` will not be changed.)

If the name is a global, then I'll do the same from the shell, using 
`sed`:

```
for f in $(find root -name '*.hh' -o -name '*.cc')
do
    sed 's/\<oldname\>/newname/g' $f > tmp && mv tmp $x
done
```

If you're under Windows, I believe VS has similar possiblities, with a
global search and replace over all source files in the solution.

You don't compile to find errors you know are there; it's generally
easier to fix them first.

Comment: `You don't compile to find errors you know are there` Why not? Finding errors is something the compiler does well; why should I have to do it myself?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If you know the error is there, then you don't need the compiler to find it for you.  Compiling is just a waste of time.  If you know that `oldname` is no longer a valid symbol, it's much faster to just change it everywhere to `newname` than it is to have to compile, then iterate through the errors.

Comment: I trust my compiler -- with its fully-featured C++ parser -- over a blunt find-and-replace. Of course if I'm really changing all instances of a symbol then I'll try that manually first, but in the general case I don't see any reason not to rely on the compiler for stuff.

Comment: Global search and replace not always help. Multiple functions, structs, namespaces, etc can have fields with the same name. 

This can lead to bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) or a [MELT](https://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt) extension to do that. In 2021 MELT is obsolete (because of lack of funding). Perhaps [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) could be used in spring 2021.

You could also patch the GCC source code. It is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html).

But I really don't think it is worth the effort (it probably would take you more than one day). You might try also some alternative compiler, e.g. [LLVM/Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/).

My feeling is that you just should recompile and correct your source code till you get no warnings (with `gcc -Wall -Wextra`) or errors. It is pragmatically the simplest and easiest approach.

You could also try the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) or be interested by the European [DECODER](https://www.decoder-project.eu/) project.

Most importantly, **you should** (for a large software coded in C or C++) **document some coding conventions** and **do some [code review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_review) in your team**. [MISRA C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MISRA_C) or the [GNU coding conventions](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/) could be inspirational; or those documented and followed in [GTK](https://gtk.org/) or in [Qt](https://qt.io/).

BTW, your question is surprising in 2021. Since in practice, GCC takes only a few seconds to recompile most C++ translation units. Of course, there are known exceptions with weird template expansion, but in my opinion a compilation time of more than ten seconds per C++ source file is a symptom inviting to recode that file.

---

#### practical advice with Emacs

You could configure e.g. your [`emacs` editor](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) to compile with a single key press (e.g. bind `F11` functiion key of your keyboard to `recompile` emacs action, and e.g. bind `F10` function key to skip to next error, e.g. put that in your `.emacs` :

```
 ; inside .emacs
 (global-set-key [f10] 'next-error)
 (global-set-key [f11] 'recompile)
```

Comment: Do you know of a vim equivalent?

Comment: No. I don't use `vim` and my feeling is that `vim`'s philosophy is to compile *outside* of the editor, while Emacs's philosophy is to do everything (but the kitchen sink...). That's why I personally prefer `emacs` over `vim`. You might have another terminal screen where you repeatly run `make`

Comment: I have never used emacs but after I saw http://1010.co.uk/gneve.html, I can believe you.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: No, vim's philosophy is to *debug* outside the editor, but you certainly compile from vim and it has built-in support for list of errors and jumping to them.